# Error in calculating the increase function with micrometer

Tags: prometheus, quarkus, micrometer, prometheus-operator

I'm generating custom metrics with micrometer using quarkus, when executing the "increase" function directly in prometheus the value presented for the calculation is wrong.[image]

I believe that there is something wrong in the calculation of the rate [1m], because it is showing the accumulated value of the counter.

The accumulated of day for this event is 18150, but the increase represents 82026:

[image]

[image]

Could this be prometheus configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The metric is showing the total for all requests that happened in that 1 minute window.

Your second image [1m] is showing the 'vector'. Remove the `[1m]` to see the actual total.

If your goal is to show the average duration of requests in that 1 minute window you need to divide it by the total request count.

I'm not certain on the metric names, but you would need something like this:

```
increase(fsm_entrypoint_timer_seconds_total[1m]) /
increase(fsm_entrypoint_timer_seconds_count[1m])
```

Comment: i need show the total of events that occurring during the last 1m, for example. 

I understand that the query below should present the total of events in the 1m period, but the calculation is wrong.
increase(fsm_entrypoint_timer_seconds_count[1m])

Comment: Is it possible there were 82,000 requests in that 1 minute? What do you think the amount should be?

Comment: I added in the description a print with the total of events that were received on the day, total 18150, but the increase shows 82026.